# Which type is x (cancel) like icon displays when type something in searchbar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uicolor

I am working with search bar in swift 6.3, my problem is described in the image which i am attached.

[image: The image shows what i want?]

I tried something like this :

Code:

```
             for subview in searchBar.subviews{
        for another in subview.subviews {

            if another.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
                for each in another.subviews {
                    if each.isKindOfClass(UIButton){
              println("it is button")

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Code Description:

Find the textfield from search bar, after checks all subviews in textfield.As well as also checked all subviews in search bar.But not working.

Please give the reason , anyone give down vote not only for this post but also for any post.Then only can improve the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use below method to set the images for search bar icons..

```
setImage(_:forSearchBarIcon:state:)
```

Reference [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state:)

Comment: Is there any way to change the color

Comment: how to make it to default clear button after some time

Comment: You need to play around images.. You need to make default clear image & need to set after some time...

Comment: "var canceIcon = UIImage(named:"" )
        searchBar.setImage(canceIcon, forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal) " is worked for me.Thanks

Comment: ya but actually my question was the change the color.Thats why i did not accept.gave up vote

Answer (score 0):

in objective-C i founded one similar solutions.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to change the color of clear icon.

Comment: yes , now its cannot becasue that searchbaricon is contstant